# Query to find 'most watched' [COUNT()] from one table while returning the results from another

Tags: asp.net, sql

The question probably is quite confusing.

In affect i have the following:

```
WatchList table
 UserId | FilmId
|   3        77
|  etc       etc
|
|
|
```

these are foreign keys for the following tables

```
FilmDB - Film_title, Film_plot, Film_Id etc.
```

and

```
aspnet_memberships - UserId, Username etc..
```

Now, i presume i will need to use a join but i am struggling with the syntax.

I would like to use 'Count' on the 'WatchList' and return the most frequent filmId's and their counterpart information, but i'd then like to return the REST of the FilmDB results, essentially giving me a list of ALL films, but with those found in the WatchedList my frequently sorted to the top.

Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: which dbms..sql server ? specify MOST FREQUENTED ... top most watched film ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM filmdb 
  LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT filmid, count(*) AS cnt
         FROM watch_list 
        GROUP BY filmid) AS a
    ON filmdb.film_id = a.filmid
 ORDER BY isnull(cnt, 0) DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46b16/10

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify if the query should be grouped by film_id or user_id. The example I have provided is grouped by user if you change that to film_id then you will get the watch count for all users per film.

You need to use a subquery to get the count and then order the results by the count descending to get an ordered list.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        WatchList.Film_Id,
        WatchCount=COUNT(*)
        FilmDB.Film_Title
    FROM
        WatchList
        INNER JOIN FilmDB ON FilmDB.Film_Id=WatchList.Film_Id
    GROUP BY
        WatchList.UserID,
            WatchList.Film_Id,
            FilmDB.Film_Title
)AS X 
ORDER BY
    WatchCount DESC
```